# Highmaps - how i can have a seperate legend by different report?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, highmaps

I have two (or more) reports, i want to combine this two reports and show in one map by a separate legend.

Please see [example](http://jsfiddle.net/zp4v7kjw/).

Also the result shared in tooltip when legends are visible.

```
    $(function () {

    // Initiate the chart
    $('#container').highcharts('Map', {
        plotOptions : {
                map : {
                    mapData: Highcharts.maps['countries/ir/ir-all'],
                joinBy: 'hc-key',
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        color: '#BADA55'
                    }
                },
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '{point.name}'
                }
            }
        },
        title : {
            text : 'Highmaps basic demo'
        },

        mapNavigation: {
            enabled: true,
            buttonOptions: {
                verticalAlign: 'bottom'
            }
        },

        series : [{
          name : 'Report 1',
          data : [{
            'hc-key' : "ir-ea",
            value : 1000,
          },{
            'hc-key' : "ir-kv",
            value : 1000,
          },{
            'hc-key' : "ir-kd",
            value : 1000,
          },{
            'hc-key' : "ir-wa",
            value : 1000,
          }],
          mapData: Highcharts.maps['countries/ir/ir-all'],
          joinBy: 'hc-key',
          states: {
            hover: {
              color: '#BADA55'
            }
          },
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            style : {
              textShadow : '',
            },
            format: '<span style="color:black">{point.name}</span>',
          }
        },{
          name : 'Report 2',
          data : [{
            'hc-key' : "ir-wa",
            value : '3000',
          },{
            'hc-key' : "ir-ea",
            value : '3000',
          }],
          mapData: Highcharts.maps['countries/ir/ir-all'],
          joinBy: 'hc-key',
          states: {
            hover: {
              color: '#BADA55'
            }
          },
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            style : {
              textShadow : '',
            },
            format: '<span style="color:black">{point.name}</span>',
          }
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this is not end answer, only a better solution.

i added `legendItemClick` event for better view.

Please see [example](http://jsfiddle.net/zp4v7kjw/1/).

```
            events : {
              legendItemClick : function(){
                  for(i=0; i < this.chart.series.length; i++) {
                      this.chart.series[i].hide();
                  }

            },
        },
```

but i want share same province data. for example, i have `value = 1` in `Golestan` province in report 1 and i have `value = 3` in `Golestan` province in report 2. sum of result tooltip is :

```
Report 1
 Golestan : 1
Report 2
 Golestan : 3
Sum
 Goelstan : 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. What I have missed so far is to make the tooltip appear even if there is no value for the currently selected report.

[This code in jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/zp4v7kjw/5/) Is this what you are trying to establish?

```
$(function() {

    // Initiate the chart
    $('#container').highcharts('Map', {
        plotOptions: {
            map: {
                mapData: Highcharts.maps['countries/ir/ir-all'],
                joinBy: 'hc-key',
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        color: '#BADA55'
                    }
                },
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '{point.name}'
                },
                events: {
                    legendItemClick: function() {
                        for (i = 0; i < this.chart.series.length; i++) {
                            this.chart.series[i].hide();
                        }

                    },
                },
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Highmaps basic demo'
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                var pointName = this.point.name;

                function filterByName(value) {
                    return (value.hasOwnProperty("name") && typeof value.name !== "undefined" && value.name === pointName);
                }

                var result = "<b>" + this.point.name + "</b><br>";
                var allSeries = this.series.chart.series;
                var curSeries, curValue;
                for (var i = 0; i < allSeries.length; i++) {
                    curSeries = allSeries[i];
                    curValue = curSeries.points.filter(filterByName);
                    if (curValue.length === 0 || (curValue[0].hasOwnProperty("value") && curValue[0].value == null)) {
                        return result;
                    }
                    curValue = curValue[0].value;
                    result += '<br><b>' + curSeries.name + '</b> ' + curValue;
                }
                return result;
            }
        },

        mapNavigation: {
            enabled: true,
            buttonOptions: {
                verticalAlign: 'bottom'
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Report 1',
            visible: false,
            data: [{
                'hc-key': "ir-ea",
                value: 1000,
            }, {
                'hc-key': "ir-kv",
                value: 1000,
            }, {
                'hc-key': "ir-kd",
                value: 1000,
            }, {
                'hc-key': "ir-wa",
                value: 1000,
            }],
            mapData: Highcharts.maps['countries/ir/ir-all'],
            joinBy: 'hc-key',
            states: {
                hover: {
                    color: '#BADA55'
                }
            },
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                style: {
                    textShadow: '',
                },
                format: '<span style="color:black">{point.name}</span>',
            }
        }, {
            name: 'Report 2',
            data: [{
                'hc-key': "ir-wa",
                value: '3000',
            }, {
                'hc-key': "ir-ea",
                value: '3000',
            }],
            mapData: Highcharts.maps['countries/ir/ir-all'],
            joinBy: 'hc-key',
            states: {
                hover: {
                    color: '#BADA55'
                }
            },
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                style: {
                    textShadow: '',
                },
                format: '<span style="color:black">{point.name}</span>',
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: no .[see example](http://jsfiddle.net/zp4v7kjw/9/). when click on report 1(r1) and report 2(r2) , r1 && r2 must be join and show the both blue and black such as legends in line report. thanks for answer. but in `answer 2` i find better solution.